# How to prevent CakePHP 3.0 from extending session timeout with ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, session-cookies, cakephp-3.0

How can I prevent CakePHP 3.x from extending my users session when background ajax calls are made to the server? I am using jquery's $.ajax() as well.

I have a setInterval running once a minute to get some user notifications. My application is an EHR and I need to maintain strict session timeout. My get notifications Javascript basically just made my sessions unlimited because the ajax calls are extending the sessions.

I thought a saw something in the CakePHP book about this a few weeks ago but I can't seem to find it today.

Thanks,
Daren

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean when you say "_strict session timeout_"? From the title of your question one could think that you just want the background AJAX requests to no affect the timeout, while the foreground activity by the user _should_ extend the session?

Comment: Strict in that the session must timeout after 10 minutes of no activity. So background Ajax requests should not extend the session. Which right now my Ajax requests are extending the session which in my use case is undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is something that you need to handle on your own, ie implement your own timeout mechanism. How to handle it, depends.

You want to exclude AJAX background activity only, so you need to have access to the request object, and you most probably want to handle this as early as possible. Given this prerequisites, I'd probably use a dispatcher filter, where you can extend the timeout depending on whether or not the current request is an AJAX request, and destroy the session before any controllers are involved.

Here's a very basic, pretty much self-explantory example, which assumes that the `timeout` option value is set for the [**session configuration**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration).

**src/Routing/Filter/SessionTimeoutFilter.php**

```
namespace App\Routing\Filter;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter;

class SessionTimeoutFilter extends DispatcherFilter
{
    public function beforeDispatch(Event $event)
    {
        /* @var $request \Cake\Network\Request */
        $request = $event->data['request'];

        $session = $request->session();
        $lastAccess = $session->read('SessionTimeoutFilter.lastAccess');

        if (
            $lastAccess !== null &&
            time() - $lastAccess > Configure::read('Session.timeout') * 60
        ) {
            $request->session()->destroy();
        }

        if (!$request->is('ajax')) {
            $session->write('SessionTimeoutFilter.lastAccess', time());
        }
    }
}
```

**src/config/bootstrap.php**

```
DispatcherFactory::add('SessionTimeout');
```

Depending on your specific needs, you can of course place similar code pretty much anywhere in your application where you have access to the request object.

Comment: Worked Perfectly. I did add another check to see if a querystring param was set so I could allow an ajax ping request to extend the session. I have some session monitoring javascript that extends the session if they are active on the form page. If they leave un-submitted work on the page, I have a special popup that allows them to re-authenticate so they don't lose their work. I had a user notification script that was checking for new notifications that was basically extending the session forever, which wasn't allowing the auto logoff after X minutes to work.