# Prevent ajax calls from updating session timeout with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I'm using some long pooling in JavaScript of this kind:

```
setInterval(demo, 3000);

function demo(){
    $.get(url, params, function(data){
        //whatever
    });
}
```

Being `url` a URL to a CakePHP controller action returning JSON.

But I want my session to only last 20 minutes since the user last action on the screen. This is, ignoring the pooling which is taking place every 30 seconds. 
Otherwise the session will last forever.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Use a Cake3 **or** Cake2 tag. It doesn't make much sense to tag a question for both versions.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298817/how-to-prevent-cakephp-3-0-from-extending-session-timeout-with-ajax-requests** That is for 3.x, but it's the same concept in 2.x, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this in app controller in beforeFilter function

```
if(!$this->request->is('ajax')){
             $LastActivity = $this->Session->read('LastActivity');
             if ($LastActivity != '' && (time() - $LastActivity) > 1200) {//for 20 minute
                $this->Auth->logout();
                $this->redirect('/');
            }
             $this->Session->write('LastActivity', time());
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the last login time in the session when a request happens compare it to the current time when a request comes in. If the current time is greater than last login time + 20min call the [logout() method of the auth component](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#_logout).